# Spring JPA change datasource depending on request header

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-rest

I developed an application with spring-data-rest.
I love it and it works like a charme.

What I want to do (to implement one backend for multiple customers) is to change the datasource of my repository depending on an apikey which is sent in a custom request header.

The connection info (url, credentials, database) can be retrieved from an external microservice which manages all the database configurations.

The idea is to retrieve all available database connections on startup and store them in a map with apikey as key and the connection info as value.

I´m not clear about how I can change the datasource of my repo for each incoming request at runtime.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found a solution using the AbstractRoutingDataSource.
This article saved my day. A really easy to use and to understand solution.
http://fizzylogic.nl/2016/01/24/Make-your-Spring-boot-application-multi-tenant-aware-in-2-steps/

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your JPA provider, what you are wanting will be multi-tenancy support.

For Hibernate, there is a nice [multi-tenancy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html) API available that plugs in with Spring very nicely for configuring what data source to use. [MultiTenantConnectionProvider](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/spi/MultiTenantConnectionProvider.html) and [CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/spi/CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver.html) for some API details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. multi-tenancy pushed me in the right direction. Upvote for this.